# refresh page containing axaj loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a .load() script to change the content on a webpage as a means to navigate the site.  Thus the urls are as follows:
www.123.com/front/#index
www.123.com/front/#about
www.123.com/front/#contact

When the page is reloaded, I want it to return to the initial content (ie www.123.com/front/ or www.123.com/front/#index ) but I am having trouble doing this.

I have tried using a http-equiv="refresh" meta tag, but that can only be applied in the , thus leading to an infinite reloading loop.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can check the hash on document ready, and change/reload the page if it's not the index...

```
$(function () {
    var indexHash = "#index";
    if (window.location.hash && window.location.hash !== indexHash) {
        window.location.hash = indexHash;
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```